# What is the best way to replace the format of data in a large dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, data-science, data-cleaning

I am just starting out with data science, so apologies if this is a bone question with a simple answer, but I have been scanning google for hours and have tried multiple solutions to no avail.

Basically, my dataset has automatically adjusted some values such as 3-5 to 03-May. I am not able to simply change the values in Excel, rather I need to clean the data in Python. My first thought was simply to use the replace tool i.e. `df = df.replace('2019-05-03 00:00:00', '3-5')` but it doesn't work, presumably as the dtype is different between the timestamp and the str(?) - it works if I adjust the code i.e. `df = df.replace('0-2', '3-5')`.

I can't simply add that data as a missing value either as it is simply an error in formatting rather than a spurious entry.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Listed below is an example snippet of the data I am working with:

[image]

[GitHub public gist](https://gist.github.com/LairdMaccles/edcc8873eee72c0f23113e27fa394762.js)

PSB for code:

```
#Dependencies
import pytest
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
import numpy as np
from google.colab import drive
import io

#Import data
from google.colab import files
upload = files.upload()
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(upload['breast-cancer.xls']))

df

#Clean Data
df.types

#Correcting tumor-size and inv-nodes values
'''def clean_data(dataset):
      for i in dataset:
         dataset = dataset.replace('2019-05-03 00:00:00','3-5')
         dataset = dataset.replace('2019-08-06 00:00:00','6-8')
         dataset = dataset.replace('2019-09-11 00:00:00','9-11')
         dataset = dataset.replace('2014-12-01 00:00:00','12-14')
         dataset = dataset.replace('2014-10-01 00:00:00','10-14')
         dataset = dataset.replace('2019-09-05 00:00:00','5-9')
      return dataset

   cleaned_dataset = dataset.apply(clean_data)
   cleaned_dataset'''

df = df.replace('2019-05-03 00:00:00', '3-5')
df

#Check for duplicates
df.duplicated()
```

Comment: You’ll need to show your python code and your data in text form for us to help you.

Comment: I have attached some code but it is messy, better to click the GitHub public gist link I attached - data visible there too.

Comment: try finding the type of the exact element you want to replace and replace that, or convert column to str with .astype(str). still can't get to your data so no tested answer...

Answer (score 0):

`df[['tumor-size', 'inv-nodes']] = df[['tumor-size', 'inv-nodes']].astype(str)`

That line of code saved the day.